# How do I declare class variables through typescript *.d.ts

Tags: typescript

I have a class. Let's say

```
export class Person {
   constructor(options = {
      name: string,
      age: number,
      height: string,
      weight: number
     } as PersonOptions) {
        this.name = options.name
        this.age = options.age
        this.height = options.height
        this.weight = options.weight
     }
 }
```

PersonOptions is valid. But how can I declare variables inside of `this` in a different file?

Comment: What do you mean and why do you need to do it?

Comment: @kelly anything following `this` is underlined in red "property age does not exist on type Person".. how do i make it exist

Comment: Please read the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html)

Comment: i have dawg @kelly

Comment: The first thing in there is defining properties on a class.